# Suppose $f: R^n$ to $R$ is positive, continuous and $\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} f (x) = 0$. Prove that $f$ attains its maximum somewhere on $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

My approach so far:

Let $\epsilon = 1$. Then there is $R>0$ s.t: $||x|| > R \implies |f(x)| < 1$. It follows that $f$ is bounded by $1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{$closed ball  of radius $R$ centered at $0\}$ (sorry, not sure how to latex closure of a set).

I am wondering if I can just consider $f$ mapping the closed ball of radius $R$ centered at $0$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Also, why is this allowed? If so, I can use the theorem that if $f$ is continuous on compact set, then the image set is compact. I believe I can finish it from here. Thanks.

Comment: Taking $\epsilon = 1$ is a bad idea... Why should there be any $x$ with $f(x)\ge 1$?

Comment: If $f$ is constant zero you are done. Otherwise there exists $x_0$ such that $a = |f(x_0)|\neq 0$. Now, choose your radius such that $|f(x)| < a$ outside. What can be said inside?

Comment: I don't know, my professor took epsilon to be equal to 1 during class. I'm going off of what he did

Comment: I see nothing wrong with taking $\epsilon=1$. If there are no points with $f(x)\geq{1}$, what of it?

Comment: given that $f$ is a continuous function defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $|f|$ is bounded on any finite region, as the spheres $S_R = \{x \ \mid \ \|x\| < R \}$.  $|f|$ is continuous hence $|f|$ attains its maximum on $S_R$ : $m_f(R) = \sup_{x \in S_R} |f(x)|$, hence if $|f|$ attains its maximum nowhere then $m_f(R)  \to \infty$ when $R \to \infty$

Comment: @user1952009 the fact that $|f|$ attains a maximum on $S_R$ follows from the extreme value theorem correct? Then we need a compact set, so shouldn't $S_R$ be taken to be its closure?

Comment: yes it's a typo,$\|x\| \le R$. and yes the extreme value theorem, or the theorem that the image by a continuous function of a closed subset is closed (whatever its name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U = \{x | f(x) \ge f(0) \}$, note that $U$ is closed. Also note that if $f$ has a point at which it attains a maximum, then the point is in $U$.

Choose $M$ such that if $\|x\| > M$ then
$f(x) < {1 \over 2} f(0)$. Then $U \subset B(0,M)$ and so $U$ is bounded. Hence
$U$ is compact.